# R unexpected rounding by writing in .csv and in a database

Tags: r

I am having the following issue. I have numeric values with about 10-20 decimals. I am writing those values in .csv (via write.csv2()) and in a database (via SQLSave() from the RODBC package). All decimals are for me relevant. 
Unfortunately R rounds up the numbers after the 8th decimal.

As an example:

> 5655698.697843645699322

Becomes:

> 5655698,69784365

I tried to increase the number of digits (`$digits` in `options()`) but this is affecting only the number of digits I see in the console.
I tried with `format(,digits=x)` and this is working. However since I have a large number columns this is quite costly and it does not look as a clean solution.

Is there another way to increase the number of digits by writing in .csv and in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R uses 64-bit IEEE double precision as its base numeric format. This has a limit of precision of 14-15 *significant figures* (not decimal places). So R is just writing out the numbers to the correct limit of its accuracy.

If you want more decimals, you can use a package for arbitrary-precision arithmetic:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/index.html

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/index.html

Comment: Thanks for that. Could you provide an example on how I can use this. I tried the following to increase precision: mpfr(c, precBits = 113). But also in this case it creates decimals which do not exists. Indeed I get the following number: 5655698.69784364569932222366333007812.

Comment: That's probably because when you read your data in, R silently discarded the excess precision. You'll need to import your data using any facilities provided by gmp and/or Rmpfr.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this (but this works for only txt file not csv file)?

```
 x<-5655698.697843645699322
 y<-sprintf("%.15f",x)
[1] "5655698.697843645699322"

 write(y,"x.txt")
```

Updated:

```
y<-format(round(x, 15), nsmall = 15)
write(y,"x.txt")

 y<-format(round(x, 25), nsmall = 25)
Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  : 
  invalid 'nsmall' argument
```

The error means you can't increase the decimal by more than 15 (as per argument `nsmall`)

```
 y<-format(round(x, 25), nsmall = 15)
> y
[1] "5655698.697843645699322"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint however this seems to have a strange behavior. I´ve run the following: x<-5655698.697843645699322; y<-sprintf("%.25f",x); write(y,"x.txt"). I get the following result: 5655698.6978436456993222236633301. If I increase the number of decimals it creates additional decimals which do not exists(????).